# How to get rid of massive Memory leak with blurred image in uitableview cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, ios7

Somehow when I scroll to the bottom of my table (96 items only) I get 1 gb of memory usage (it increase for every cell that gets created. I have a table that has an image with a blurred image in front of it that is using a cropped version of the original image with text then on top of that. Pretty simple. I'm using the apple provided sample code for blurring images available here: https://github.com/iGriever/TWSReleaseNotesView/blob/master/TWSReleaseNotesView/UIImage%2BImageEffects.m

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"itemCell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

NSDictionary *foodItem = [self.foodItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

// Set up the image view
UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
UIImage *foodImage = [UIImage imageNamed:[foodItem objectForKey:FOOD_IMAGE_FILE_KEY]];
[imageView setImage:foodImage];
[imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill];

// Set up the label
UILabel *labelView = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:2];
[labelView setFont:[UIFont flatFontOfSize:20.0]];
labelView.text = @"Blah";

// Set up the image view
UIImageView *blurredView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:3];

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

    UIImage *blurredImage = [[self cropForBlur:foodImage] applyBlurWithRadius:4
                                                                tintColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0 alpha:0.2]
                                                    saturationDeltaFactor:1.2
                                                                maskImage:nil];

    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        blurredView.image = blurredImage;
    });
});

return cell;
```

}

*Note: I know it is most likely the blur (as opposed to my cropping) as it only happens when I do the blur. Also it's nothing to do with the async dispatch stuff as it still happens if I don't do that.

Yes I'm using ARC. Yes I'm using storyboards.

Here's cropForBlur:

```
- (UIImage *)cropForBlur:(UIImage *)originalImage
{
    CGSize size = [originalImage size];
    int startCroppingPosition = 100;
    if (size.height > size.width) {
        startCroppingPosition = size.height/2 + ((size.width / 320) * 45);
    } else {
        startCroppingPosition = size.height/2 + ((size.width / 320) * 45);
    }
    // WTF: Don't forget that the CGImageCreateWithImageInRect believes that
    // the image is 180 rotated, so x and y are inverted, same for height and width.
    CGRect cropRect = CGRectMake(0, startCroppingPosition, size.width, ((size.width/320) * 35));
    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([originalImage CGImage], cropRect);
    UIImage *newImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef scale:(size.width/160) orientation:originalImage.imageOrientation];
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);
    return newImage;
}
```

I've also tried looking in Instruments but it will show that I'm using heaps of memory in total but the big chunks of memory don't show up in the breakdown. Weird.

Here's the bit that's saying I am using heaps of memory in the left bar.
[image]

Here's the allocations bit in Instruments. I don't see how they could match up. I haven't got zombies on or anything (unless there's somewhere other that in edit scheme to change that).
[image]

Here's the leaks Instruments view after scrolling down a bit. Doesn't seem to show any real leaks :S So confused.
[image]

Comment: Looks good, but not enough information,
can you provide cropForBlue: implementation?
And you are using ARC?

Comment: There you go. Although, I don't think it is anything to do with the cropping.

Comment: So if you comment blur-creating code your app won't consume so much memory?

Comment: Correct :) It stays below 20 mb.

Comment: Have you tried the Leaks instrument?  It will show you what object was leaked and then the whole lifecycle of when it was created, along with who retained and released it.

Comment: Seems like xcode bug. Instruments is stable debugging tool and xcode performance monitor was introduced in xcode 5, so I don't rely on it very much. Anyway, the answer above or below (it jumps) isn't correct - you don't get a retain cycle, the block will be released after background queue execute it.

Comment: Yea I tried that. It doesn't seem to actually show any sizeable leaks. I'll post up the instruments screenshot. I'm not too pro on instruments though so maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: I got some idea.
Run your app in xcode, open performce monitor with over 1 gb memory usage and click 'profile in instruments' button. If instruments wont show such memory usage - its xcode bug

Comment: I am having the same problem with Apple's blur function.. Were you able to solve it? @GeorgeMcKibbin

Comment: @EralpB No, I wasn't able to fix it. Let me know if you find anything.

Comment: @GeorgeMcKibbin I am not really sure but If you look at my self-answered question (http://stackoverflow.com/a/26330589/1066820), I might have a lead.. I solved it but I wouldn't want to face it one more time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the solution from this [link](http://expertland.net/question/1930j1fa7q7x8x3p3z2t30bz4254l3s1c7/detail.html). The problem is the image has a different scale from your screen scale. The final output image can be very big.