# Memory Leak in Objective C function with ARC

Tags: objective-c, ios7, memory-leaks, core-graphics, uigraphicscontext

here is the function from the library MGSpotyViewController, but I am asking what to watch out in this kind of situations.

I am used to C++ and maintaining my own objects but I can't find the problem here. I tried very basic pieces of codes with `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` and memory still increased slightly but I wasn't sure if I located the problem or that's because the GC hasn't run yet.

To test the following function I did:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    UIImage* image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Dude.png"];

    for (int i =0; i<1000; i++) {
        @autoreleasepool {
            // doesn't matter if i move the first line here.
            UIImage *blurredImage = [image applyBlurWithRadius:20.0f
                                                 tintColor:nil
                                     saturationDeltaFactor:1.0f
                                                 maskImage:nil];
        }

    }
}
```

The result was like this:

[image: instruments-allocation]

What is/might be the problem?

UIImage+ImageEffects.m

```
- (UIImage *)applyBlurWithRadius:(CGFloat)blurRadius tintColor:(UIColor *)tintColor saturationDeltaFactor:(CGFloat)saturationDeltaFactor maskImage:(UIImage *)maskImage
{
    // Check pre-conditions.
    if(self.size.width < 1 || self.size.height < 1) {
        NSLog (@"*** error: invalid size: (%.2f x %.2f). Both dimensions must be >= 1: %@", self.size.width, self.size.height, self);
        return nil;
    }
    if(!self.CGImage) {
        NSLog (@"*** error: image must be backed by a CGImage: %@", self);
        return nil;
    }
    if(maskImage && !maskImage.CGImage) {
        NSLog (@"*** error: maskImage must be backed by a CGImage: %@", maskImage);
        return nil;
    }

    CGRect imageRect = { CGPointZero, self.size };
    UIImage *effectImage = self;
    CGFloat scale = 0.5f;
    scale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];

    BOOL hasBlur = blurRadius > __FLT_EPSILON__;
    BOOL hasSaturationChange = fabs(saturationDeltaFactor - 1.) > __FLT_EPSILON__;
    if(hasBlur || hasSaturationChange) {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.size, NO, scale);
        CGContextRef effectInContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        CGContextScaleCTM(effectInContext, 1.0, -1.0);
        CGContextTranslateCTM(effectInContext, 0, -self.size.height);
        CGContextDrawImage(effectInContext, imageRect, self.CGImage);

        vImage_Buffer effectInBuffer;
        effectInBuffer.data     = CGBitmapContextGetData(effectInContext);
        effectInBuffer.width    = CGBitmapContextGetWidth(effectInContext);
        effectInBuffer.height   = CGBitmapContextGetHeight(effectInContext);
        effectInBuffer.rowBytes = CGBitmapContextGetBytesPerRow(effectInContext);

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.size, NO, scale);
        CGContextRef effectOutContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        vImage_Buffer effectOutBuffer;
        effectOutBuffer.data     = CGBitmapContextGetData(effectOutContext);
        effectOutBuffer.width    = CGBitmapContextGetWidth(effectOutContext);
        effectOutBuffer.height   = CGBitmapContextGetHeight(effectOutContext);
        effectOutBuffer.rowBytes = CGBitmapContextGetBytesPerRow(effectOutContext);

        if(hasBlur) {
            // A description of how to compute the box kernel width from the Gaussian
            // radius (aka standard deviation) appears in the SVG spec:
            // http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/filters.html#feGaussianBlurElement
            // 
            // For larger values of 's' (s >= 2.0), an approximation can be used: Three
            // successive box-blurs build a piece-wise quadratic convolution kernel, which
            // approximates the Gaussian kernel to within roughly 3%.
            //
            // let d = floor(s * 3*sqrt(2*pi)/4 + 0.5)
            // 
            // ... if d is odd, use three box-blurs of size 'd', centered on the output pixel.
            // 
            CGFloat inputRadius = blurRadius * scale;
            NSUInteger radius = floor(inputRadius * 3. * sqrt(2 * M_PI) / 4 + 0.5);
            if(radius % 2 != 1) {
                radius += 1; // force radius to be odd so that the three box-blur methodology works.
            }
            vImageBoxConvolve_ARGB8888(&effectInBuffer, &effectOutBuffer, NULL, 0, 0, (int)radius, (int)radius, 0, kvImageEdgeExtend);
            vImageBoxConvolve_ARGB8888(&effectOutBuffer, &effectInBuffer, NULL, 0, 0, (int)radius, (int)radius, 0, kvImageEdgeExtend);
            vImageBoxConvolve_ARGB8888(&effectInBuffer, &effectOutBuffer, NULL, 0, 0, (int)radius, (int)radius, 0, kvImageEdgeExtend);
        }
        BOOL effectImageBuffersAreSwapped = NO;
        if(hasSaturationChange) {
            CGFloat s = saturationDeltaFactor;
            CGFloat floatingPointSaturationMatrix[] = {
                0.0722 + 0.9278 * s,  0.0722 - 0.0722 * s,  0.0722 - 0.0722 * s,  0,
                0.7152 - 0.7152 * s,  0.7152 + 0.2848 * s,  0.7152 - 0.7152 * s,  0,
                0.2126 - 0.2126 * s,  0.2126 - 0.2126 * s,  0.2126 + 0.7873 * s,  0,
                                  0,                    0,                    0,  1,
            };
            const int32_t divisor = 256;
            NSUInteger matrixSize = sizeof(floatingPointSaturationMatrix)/sizeof(floatingPointSaturationMatrix[0]);
            int16_t saturationMatrix[matrixSize];
            for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < matrixSize; ++i) {
                saturationMatrix[i] = (int16_t)roundf(floatingPointSaturationMatrix[i] * divisor);
            }
            if(hasBlur) {
                vImageMatrixMultiply_ARGB8888(&effectOutBuffer, &effectInBuffer, saturationMatrix, divisor, NULL, NULL, kvImageNoFlags);
                effectImageBuffersAreSwapped = YES;
            }
            else {
                vImageMatrixMultiply_ARGB8888(&effectInBuffer, &effectOutBuffer, saturationMatrix, divisor, NULL, NULL, kvImageNoFlags);
            }
        }
        if(!effectImageBuffersAreSwapped)
            effectImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        if(effectImageBuffersAreSwapped)
            effectImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    }

    // Set up output context.
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.size, NO, scale);
    CGContextRef outputContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextScaleCTM(outputContext, 1.0, -1.0);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(outputContext, 0, -self.size.height);

    // Draw base image.
    CGContextDrawImage(outputContext, imageRect, self.CGImage);

    // Draw effect image.
    if(hasBlur) {
        CGContextSaveGState(outputContext);
        if(maskImage) {
            CGContextClipToMask(outputContext, imageRect, maskImage.CGImage);
        }
        CGContextDrawImage(outputContext, imageRect, effectImage.CGImage);
        CGContextRestoreGState(outputContext);
    }

    // Add in color tint.
    if(tintColor) {
        CGContextSaveGState(outputContext);
        CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(outputContext, tintColor.CGColor);
        CGContextFillRect(outputContext, imageRect);
        CGContextRestoreGState(outputContext);
    }

    // Output image is ready.
    UIImage *outputImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return outputImage;
}
```

Comment: ARC doesn't apply to CoreFoundation and CoreGraphics code. So objects that you Create are your responsibility to release.

Comment: According to https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/Concepts/Ownership.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001148-CJBEJBHH

Comment: I believe it's only the case when you call functions which have either Create or Copy in them. Functions with Get shouldn't be giving me ownership, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow, wow.

It turns out if the input `UIImage` to this function has scale different than `[[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]` (because I set it in the function `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions`) , it goes crazy.

I am not sure how or why, I am not sure even if this could classify as a general problem but I am going to accept this as an answer for now.